# How to track file download event in Java Servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I have such method and I need to know when a user ends to download file. But at the end of method it prints to console "end" message but download is still running. How can i track end of download event?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("GET");

    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.zip");

    File[] files = ...//getting files here

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("ABC.zip");
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    zipOut.setLevel(0);
    for (File fileToZip : files) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName());
        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        fis.close();
    }
    zipOut.close();

    fos.close();

    File my_file = new File("ABC.zip");

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.print("file download start");
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("file download end");

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'download is still running'?

Comment: In console i get message "file download end" that at the end of my message but browser still continue downloading file. I think servlet ends to work but downloading isn't finish and i don't know how to track the end of downloading then

Comment: Depending on the size of the file and the speed of the network, the server may have already flushed the `OutputStream` while the client is still busy reading. There is no way for the server to know about this.